# Python -- Efficient I/O for large number of data files

Tags: python, io

I need to aggregate daily precipitation data into monthly averages for a period of 7 years, and all the data are stored in .dat format. I know how to read in the data with NumPy and once the data are in arrays, the rest I can handle.

The problem I foresee, though, is that this is going to be an IO-bound process seeing as how I have to open and read 2360+ data files. Is there a mechanism in Python that will allow me to perform this much I/O efficiently?

I've done similar things in the past by nesting a few `for` loops inside each other and letting the thing run until it's done or my computer explodes, but I feel like there has to be a better way.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Python has multiple options to handle IO bound concurrency. AsyncIO and Threads are two common solutions that you can research.

Comment: How are the files you're reading stored? What OS and filesystem are you using? What kind of hardware underlies the filesystem (e.g is it an SSD, a single hard drive or several drives in some kind of of RAID array)? There may be only very little you can do to improve on `numpy`'s default IO routines without using platform specific tweaks. For that we'd need to know the details of your platform.

Comment: @SuperShoot I'll look in to those, thanks!

Comment: @Blckknght it's Python 2.7 on RedHat 6.7